# Running nightmare to take screenshots works but takes keeps running .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I will be using nightmare to go through quite alot of URLs and take screenshots of the pages, which I would want it to do in the background. I'm testing it out and after it takes the screenshot it keeps printing done to the console without closing and eventually closes showing:

```
Search failed: { message: 'navigation error',
  code: -7,
  details: 'Navigation timed out after 30000 ms',
  url: 'http://www.google.com' }
```

What's the best way to do what I need to do above?

```
 nightmare
    .useragent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)')
    .goto('http://www.google.com')
    .screenshot('image.png')
    .end()
    .then(console.log("done"))
    .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
     });
```

how can I get this to stop after the screenshot has been taken, shouldn't it end with the end()?

Would be grateful for any answers. Thanks

Comment: The error message should include a stacktrace. You can use that to find what is happening, obviously it's not in your actual code. Maybe a bug in one of the packages you use. Shouldn't be hard to find the actual location with the stacktrace...

Comment: @Mörre aww thanks for the comment you're such a nice guy, I found the stack trace and it worked whoop whoop